# Data modeling with the goal to get the best performance in Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, performance, database-performance, query-performance

I have a question about how I can model my stock database in order to get the best performance possible.

In SQL Server or in the Oracle, each update executed generates a little lock.

I'd like to know what's the best solution that you could tell me

**Solution 1**: create a product stock table with quantity column and for each input or output execute a SQL update against this column

**Solution 2**: create a table for product stock movement where for each input I would execute an insert with a positive quantity and for each output I would execute an insert with a negative quantity.

At the end of the day, I would execute an process for update the quantity of the stock products with the "**sum**" result of the product stock movement table
After that, I would delete all records in the product stock movement table

With **solution 1**, I would have the advantage that execute an simple select to get the product stock quantity but during the day I would have the disadvantage that have many locks due many quantity updates regarding output sold products

With **solution 2**, I'd have the disadvantage when, I will need to get the product stock quantity, I'd need to make a query with a join with product stock movement table and make a sum in all inputs and outputs of the consulted product, but in this way, during all day I wouldn't have any locks

What do you think about that two solutions presented?

Is it a good practice to make the modeling described in **solution 2**?

Thank you so much

Comment: What is the volume?  Both dbs can handle 1000s of transactions per second without locking becoming a problem -- or even noticeable.

Comment: Sounds like Solution 2 is what is known "premature optimization" which is to make non-standard design decisions to handle a performance issue that has not happened. I would go with #1 unless there is an actual performance issue. And then I would evaluate that issue and determine the best approach to fix it.

Comment: in Oracle an update creates a lock (or rather multiple locks), but usually these locks do not block concurrent operations (reads or writes). In SQL Server the effects of locking depend: with the isolation level snapshot locking usually is also not a major problem. Of course these statements are only true on the base of some premises (especially short transactions).

Comment: I believe the volume is considerable once that I need to manage 2 stores with 6 cashiers each and until December 2019 it's expected to open more 5 stores, 2 stores with 3 cashiers, 1 store with 1 cashier and 1 store with 2 cachiers, but one of the stores who has 6 cashiers will grow up to 16 cashier in 2019.

Comment: That volume is next to nothing for either RDBMS; unless one of your cashiers is Flash Gordon, you have nothing to worry about.  Our company has over 2000 people constantly saving to our CRM DB on SQL Server, we're not a massive shop, and we rarely see contention

Comment: Take a gander here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/05/how-to-fake-load-tests-with-sqlquerystress/ will give you a quick way to stress test your server, and hopefully show you it can handle far more than you ever thought possible.  If you need design pointers, then dba.stackexchange.com might be a better choice -- S/O is primarily for error resolution.  Good luck.

Comment: My worry is about the future, product stock is the core of any retail system. If I let change the modeling after, maybe I can't because maybe I will had to change many other systems who point to this module

Comment: Read up on database normalization.  As long as your database is normalized, you can have 10 users or 10,000+ users... Learn and do it right the first time and you'll be in good shape.  Again, dba.stackexchange.com is a great place for guidance on these subjects.

Comment: Best performance - do you mean read or write performance? How out of date can the stock levels be? seconds? minutes? a day? I agree that this is premature optimisation. There are many non technical parameters and constraints that need to be defined to understand what is "best". For example if you have a large budget you can solve a lot of contention issues with hardware. With regards to normalisation, this is great for the OLTP side (data entry) but not so great for the read side (up to date stock levels)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of assumptions are made here with a potential solution to a "hypothetical" problem. You don't have numbers to confidently state either of these design will lead to a problem.  We don't know your hardware specs either.

Do some due diligence first and figure out how much volume are you dealing with on a daily or monthly basis etc along with how much read/write is going to happen any given time (min/hour)? Once you have these numbers (even if they are not accurate you should get some sense of activity) run some benchmarks on the actual instance that's hosting the database (or a comparable one) for both of your solution and see for yourself what performs better.

Repeat the exercise with 3x or 5x more read/write and compare again so you are covered for the growth in future.

Decisions made with a bunch of assumptions leads to very opinionated design with always results in poor choice. Always use data to drive your decisions and validate your assumption.

PS: talking from experience here. Given we are dealing with a very large transactions, we generally have a summary table and a detail table and use triggers to update count in summary table when new records get inserted in details etc.

Good luck.